# new tag not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

im having trouble figuring out whats wrong with this code, ive added a new tag name 'light' and i cant get it to respond when i put it on the object, ive used this very similar code in the same scene but the tag has changed to ammo, or health. if i change the tag in the code to one of the older ones it responds but 'light' no response doesn't do anything. ive checked trigger is set on the cube, its essentially identical to the objects in my scene already apart from the tag being changed nd nothing. im using a free unity version 4.6.

```
 var amplitude : float = 10.0;

 function Start() {

 }

 function OnTriggerEnter (l : Collider)
 {
     if(l.tag == "light")
     {
         amplitude = 100;
     }
 }
```

Comment: What language are you actually using here? It looks like UnityScript not JavaScript. Also please *read* the tag description before you attach them to your question. `unity` != `unity3d`. The tag description explicitly tells you not to use it for `unity3d` questions.

Comment: As far as I can see the problem is not in this code snippet. Make sure that you have named the tag correctly, that an object is tagged with it, and that the colliders are correctly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a [float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), you have to add the letter `f` to the end of the value, to tell the computer that it is a float.
You have to change `var amplitude : float = 10.0;` to `var amplitude : float = 10.0f;`, and change `amplitude = 100;` to `amplitude = 100f;`.
If you don't add the `f`, the computer will change 10.0 to a double, and 100 to an int.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the problem at hand. Both 10.0 and 100 will be cast to a float in the end, and there won't be a compile error. But more importantly how do you expect these cosmetic changes to solve anything?